# Difference between MPI_Wtime and actual wall time

Tags: c, time, openmpi

I implemented a MIMD genetic algorithm using C and OpenMPI where each process takes care of a independent subpopulation (island model). So, for a population of size 200, an 1-process run operates on the whole population while 2 processes evolve populations of size 100.

So, by measuring the execution time with `MPI_Wtime`, I'm getting the expected execution time by running on a 2-core machine with ubuntu. However, it disagrees with both ubuntu's time command and perception alone: it's noticeable that running with 2 processes takes longer for some reason.

```
$time mpirun -n 1 genalg
execution time: 0.570039 s (MPI_Wtime)

real    0m0.618s
user    0m0.584s
sys     0m0.024s


$time mpirun -n 2 genalg
execution time: 0.309784 s (MPI_Wtime)

real    0m1.352s
user    0m0.604s
sys     0m0.064s
```

For a larger population (4000), I get the following:

```
$time mpirun -n 1 genalg
execution time: 11.645675 s (MPI_Wtime)

real    0m11.751s
user    0m11.292s
sys     0m0.392s


$time mpirun -n 2 genalg
execution time: 5.872798 s (MPI_Wtime)

real    0m8.047s
user    0m11.472s
sys     0m0.380s
```

I get similar results whether there's communication between the processes or not, and also tried `MPI_Barrier`. Also got the same results with `gettimeofday`, and turning gcc optimization on or off doesn't make much difference.

What is possibly going on? It should run faster with 2 processes, like `MPI_Wtime` suggests, but in reality it's running slower, matching the *real time*.

**Update**: I ran it on another PC and didn't have this issue.

The code:

```
void runGA(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    (initializations)

    if(MYRANK == 0)
        t1 = MPI_Wtime();

    genalg();
    Individual* ind = best_found();
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if(MYRANK != 0)
        return;

    t2 = MPI_Wtime();
    exptime = t2-t1;

    printf("execution time: %f s\n",exptime);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved after upgrading Ubuntu Mate 15.10 to 16.04, which came with OpenMPI version 1.10.2 (the previous one was 1.6.5).

Answer (score 1):

My guess (and [her/his](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40695/244344)) is that `time` give the sum of the time used by all cores. It's more like a cost : you have 2 processes on 2 cores, so the cost time is time1+time2 because the second core could be used for another process, so you "lost" this time on this second core. `MPI_Wtime()` display the actual time spend for the human.

It's maybe the explanation why the **real** time is lower that **user** time in the second case. The **real** time is closer to **MPI** time than the sum of **user** ans **sys**. In the 1st case the initialization time take to much time and probably false the result.

Comment: Running with 2 processes is noticeable slower though. Execution time reported by MPI_Wtime is much smaller than perceived execution time, which matches real time.

Comment: Have you collectives operations inside your code ? Because with a simple busy wait I can't reproduce your issue : https://pastebin.com/vzA8qUL7

Comment: Yes, but I have the issue even after removing the collectives.

Comment: I ran my program on another PC and couldn't replicate it either. It must be something wrong with my system...

Comment: OK, if it's a system dependent issue, you should precise it in your question, maybe someone will know why.